Summary Generation
I want to create a summary from a list of some bullet points and keywords . Most NLP and Transformer based models are not very well suited for short sentences and bullet point.
Bullet points are usually very small 1-4 words .
Most summarisers just concat the points together that is not what I am looking for
I don't wish to use a api for this a hugging face , transformer, or an LLM model would be great that i could run locally .
For Example:

Had breakfast : NO
Had Lunch : NO
Went for a jog : YES

Output :
Did not have breakfast and lunch . I went for a jog

I tried GPT-40 mini, it gave me similar to what you are looking for:  "You went for a jog but skipped both breakfast and lunch."
